# Does Android not really have wchar_t?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I built a simple method like below

```
wchar_t buf[1024] = {};
void logDebugInfo(wchar_t* fmt, ...)
{  
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vswprintf( buf, sizeof(buf), fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}

jstring Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                              jobject thiz )
{
    logDebugInfo(L"test %s, %d..", L"integer", 10);
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, buf);
}
```

I got following warning

> In function 'Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI':
>   warning: passing argument 1 of 'logDebugInfo' from incompatible pointer type
>   note: expected 'wchar_t *' but argument is of type 'unsigned int *'

And the resulting string was not correct.
If I removed that L prefix before that formatting string, weird, it worked. But L prefixes were used everywhere in my legacy code.

First I know wchar_t is not portable enough and is very compiler-specific. The size of wchar_t I expected was supposed to be 16 bits. I read some other posts which said it's 32 bits for android but wchar.h, provided by official NDK, it said wchar_t == char, really?

Comment: btw, I'm targeting android 1.6 and above

Comment: Check this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008616/want-to-force-wchar-t-to-be-an-unsigned-short-using-the-android-ndk

Comment: Already tried, fshort-wchar didn't work for me, no idea :(

Comment: I tested size of wchar_t on android by using of sizeof, it was 1...

Answer (score 15):

From NDK r5b docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html:

```
5.2/ wchar_t support:
- - - - - - - - - - -

As documented, the Android platform did not really support wchar_t until
Android 2.3. What this means in practical terms is that:

  - If you target platform android-9 or higher, the size of wchar_t is
    4 bytes, and most wide-char functions are available in the C library
    (with the exception of multi-byte encoding/decoding functions and
     wsprintf/wsscanf).

  - If you target any prior API level, the size of wchar_t will be 1 byte
    and none of the wide-char functions will work anyway.

We recommend any developer to get rid of any dependencies on the wchar_t type
and switch to better representations. The support provided in Android is only
there to help you migrate existing code.
```

Since you are targeting Android 1.6, it looks as if wchar_t is not suitable for you.

Even in the Android 2.3 platform ("android-9"), there are still notes in a number of places, including `wchar.h`, which imply that `wchar_t` is one byte and none of the wide character library functions are implemented. This suggests that the implementation may still be dodgy, so I would  be very cautious about using wchar_t on *any* Android version.

If you're looking for an alternative, I have found [UTFCPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) to be an excellent and very lightweight library.

Comment: I can't find the licensing details for UTF8-CPP. Do you know if it has any restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but I've hit this while searching for a solution.

It seems that the NDK (r8d for me) is still not supporting wsprintf:
see [issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20567)
and [code](https://github.com/android/platform_bionic/blob/master/libc/bionic/wchar.cpp).

In my case I am using libjson (considering switching to yajl) for iOS/Android shared native code.
Until I'll switch libraries, my workaround for NDK is this:

```
double value = 0.5; // for example
std::wstringstream wss;
wss << value;
return json_string(wss.str());
```

I've read that streams are slower than the C functions, and if you need a pure C (and not C++) solution it doesn't help, but maybe someone will find this useful.