# Replacing WCHAR and wchar_t with something generic

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to convert some VS 2015 C++ code to Android Studio C++ code.

My function looks like this:

```
int size = 0;
int len = 0;
fread(&size,sizeof(int),1,g_File);

#ifdef VERBOSE      
     printf("fullSentences size = %d\n",size);
#endif

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
int i3 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    fread(&len,sizeof(int),1,g_File);
    wchar_t *buff = new WCHAR[len+1];
    fread(buff,sizeof(WCHAR),len,g_File);
    buff[len]=0;
    fread(&i1,sizeof(int),1,g_File);
    fread(&i2,sizeof(int),1,g_File);
    fread(&i3,sizeof(int),1,g_File);
    fullSentences.Add(buff,i1,i2,i3);
    delete buff;

    #ifdef VERBOSE      
        FullSentence fs = fullSentences.Content().back();
        printf("%s\t%d\t%d\n",fs.Text.c_str(),fs.ByteStart,fs.ByteCount);
    #endif
}
```

I would like to get rid of the WCHAR and wchar_t in order to make the porting easier.

Can anybody suggestion a replacement for these?
I would like to avoid having to tell Android Studio what wchar_t is, if possible.

Thank you.

Edit:

Here is the class information:

```
  //
// -------------------- clsFullSentences -----------------------------
//
vector<FullSentence> &clsFullSentences::Content()
{
    return m_content;
}
vector<wstring> &clsFullSentences::CleanLower()
{
    return m_sCleanLower;
}
void clsFullSentences::LoadSerializedFullSentences(string uFile)
{
    if (!fileExists(stringToWString(uFile)))
    {
        DebugBreak();
    }

    FILE* inFile =  fopen(uFile.c_str(), "rb");

    wchar_t signature[2];
    fread(signature, sizeof(wchar_t), 1, inFile);

    wstring wline;

    //read how many possibleresults we have     
    getLineW(inFile, wline);

    unsigned int count=_wtoi(wline.c_str());

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        FullSentence st;

        getLineW(inFile,wline);
        st.Text = wline;

        //getLineW(inFile,wline);
        st.Emotion =0;// _wtoi(wline.c_str());

        getLineW(inFile,wline);
        st.ByteStart = _wtoi(wline.c_str());

        getLineW(inFile,wline);
        st.ByteCount = _wtoi(wline.c_str());

        m_content.push_back(st);
    }

    fclose(inFile);
}
void clsFullSentences::Add(wstring text, int i1, int i2, int i3)
{
    FullSentence fs;
    fs.Text = text;
    fs.Emotion = i1;
    fs.ByteStart = i2;
    fs.ByteCount = i3;
    m_content.push_back(fs);

    wstring sClean;
    sClean=StripPuncToLower(text);

    m_sCleanLower.push_back(sClean);
}

bool getLineW(FILE *inFile, wstring &result)
{
    wchar_t data[2] = { 0, 0 };

    result = L"";
    do
    {
        fread(data, sizeof(wchar_t), 1, inFile);

        if (data[0] > 0)
        {
            if (data[0] != 13)
            {
                if (data[0] != 10)
                {
                    result += data;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;//10 is the end of the line
                }
            }
        }
    } while (!feof(inFile));

    if (result.size() > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info: the declaration of `fullSentences` including its class definition is required. Given that wchar_t is 2bytes on Windows, you can try to replace it by u/int16_t, but there's no warranty it will work (fullSentences receives a wchar_t buffer and is able to extract something that looks like a std::string).

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Thanks, I have added it.

Comment: The only portable way to handle unicode strings is to store them in UTF-8 and then convert UTF-8 to wchar_t in code.

Comment: Are the files you are supposed to read create only by the application running on Android, or are you supposed to be able to read those produced by the Windows version of the app? Reason for asking: seems like Android doesn't indeed support wchar and, more importantly, wstring - which are used by the sample code. Which means the Android app won't be able to read those files without a preliminary conversion.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I create the data file on Windows, and I was hoping I could use the same file on both Windows and Android.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this code to work on Windows and Android builds then you will find that on windows wchar_t is 2 bytes, while on [android it is 4bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630255/does-android-not-really-have-wchar-t). So you will not be able to write a file on windows, and later read it properly on android. In such case you would have to use char16_t on android and convert it to 'your 
choosen' string type under android.

(edit: even better, if you can - make sure all the files are written as utf8 strings)

As for the 'choosen string type' I would suggest to use utf8, so instead of std::wstring use std::string (encoded using utf8). From my experience NDK team was discouraging use of wchar_t from the very begining (missing w* functions from c library etc.) I am not sure how it is now.

I work on a project which was originally coded with MFC, and then ported to android. We used from the very begining a TCHAR macro. Which as you know resolves to char on non unicode builds and to wchar_t on unicode builds. So the idea is to use TCHAR everywhere then under android TCHAR should resolve to char, while on windows use wchar_t (I assume you use unicode build under windows?).

I am not saying this is a best solution to share code between windows and android platform, there are lots of problems like conversions to utf8 on android, these are done with if-defs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::string` that contains text in UTF-8 encoding. You may also want some [lightweight library](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) that helps to deal with checks and conversions of such text. Avoid using `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` in code that is meant to be portable.

Comment: Do you know if I can use utfcpp both in VS2015 and in Android Studio without having to change any of my code? That would really be cool.

Comment: @tmighty Yes, it is meant to be portable and precisely for keeping your texts in same format on all platforms and for converting to platform specific formats when needed. I have not tried it with VS2015 but it worked with earlier versions of VS.

Comment: Thank you. Could you perhaps explain "Use std::string that contains text in UTF-8-encoding" a little more, perhaps with a sample? That would help me a lot.

Comment: It is like generally with portability, When you use `wchar_t` or `int` then it may be is not binary compatible in several senses. When you use `uint16_t` or `int32_t` then you may need to fix endianness to achieve binary compatibility. When you use UTF-8 text then you don't need to do anything to achieve binary compatibility.